# ESRI Flex API - Modify Style of Draw Toolbar Tooltips

Tags: arcgis-flex-api

Can anyone tell me how I can change the styling of the Draw Toolbar's tooltips in the ESRI Flex API?

If I use apply the style shown below - ALL of the application's tooltips inherit this style.  I am trying to target only the Draw toolbar here.  I have also tried intercepting the TOOL_TIP_CREATE event of various components with no luck.  That event does not fire on the map, at least when Draw toolbar tips are shown.  I can't figure out how to register that listener on the toolbar itself.

```
map.addEventListener(ToolTipEvent.TOOL_TIP_CREATE,onToolTipCreated);

<fx:Style>
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";  
        mx|ToolTip
        {
            backgroundColor: black;
            backgroundAlpha: 1.0;
            cornerRadius: 0;
            color: white;
        }
    </fx:Style
```